# Were the "wives" in the classic nursery rhyme actually the man's spouses?

Tags: etymology

In the nursery rhyme "[As I was Going to St Ives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_I_was_going_to_St_Ives)", the protagonist encounters a man and his "seven wives".

> As I was going to St Ives
>   I met a man with seven wives

Inspired by [this answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/2282/262) on Literature:SE, is there any evidence to suggest that the *typical* use for the word "wife" (in the 1700s) would encompass those who weren't a person's actual spouse or partner?

Comment: You mean, aside from the *OED* entry and citations that were already provided at the original post?

Comment: @Ily - Behind a paywall.  Also, I've not seen any distinct uses from that time period

Comment: @Ily - I'd also like to know if this was a typical usage or exceptional and whether the context excludes the usage he's referenced.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's behind a paywall. It still exists, was the original sense of the word, and continues to be used in Scots. There's a cite from 2015 for sense 1. a. *A woman.* The context doesn't exclude the usage he mentioned at all; in fact, it seems more likely than that the rhyme involved bigamy or Muslim visitors to Cornwall.

Comment: @Ily - For starters I don't think the nursery rhyme was written in Scotland..

Comment: .shrug. Well, you can continue to disbelieve in the *OED*'s existence, along with its Old and Middle English equivalents, but it has it with a horde of citations back to Old English, throughout England. You're wrong about this and there's nothing *more* authoritative than the *OED* to cite for you regarding English usage. (If it helps at all, the OE cites include their Latin glosses, which are *femina* and not *uxor*.)

Comment: The [*original*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1259672?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) of the nursery rhyme, from 1730, seems to have been:

"As I went to St. Ives,  
I met nine wives.  
And every Wife had nine Sacs,  
And every sac had nine Cats,  
And every cat had nine kittens.  
How many Wives, Sacs, Cats and Kittens   
Went to St. Ives?"

So in the original, the word *wife* might easily have meant *women*.

In Google books, I find variations of this version for over a century before we get *a man with seven wives* in the 1860s.

Comment: @PeterShor Actually, regardless of the conspiratorial denial of the *OED*, I think your post cuts the other direction. The 9 wives may easily be nine matrons wed to 9 other men, with a conversion to man with seven wives as a bit of Victorian naughtiness. That said, it's an oral tradition that goes back to memorized counting aids and Richard's original objections were poorly taken. *Wife* originally and fundamentally meant *woman* and continues to in some dialects.

Comment: **wife (n.)** Middle English *wif*, *wyf*, from Old English *wif* (neuter) "woman, female, lady," also, but not especially, "wife," ... ... Apparently felt as inadequate in its basic sense, leading to the more distinctive formation wifman (source of woman). http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=wife Usage may evolve over time. Where's the problem?

Comment: Please include the relevant research.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I have done. It's included in the link and the text. Unfortunately, as I made clear above in a comment, the actual research mentioned by another user is behind a paywall

Comment: @Richard I have no idea why you think the source is behind a paywall. It took me three seconds of googling to find the Oxford English Dictionary's website. I typed in the word "wife", and arrived at this page: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228941?redirectedFrom=wife#eid, where the first heading defined wife as "A woman considered without reference to marital status, and related senses." The page then cited examples ranging from 1300 to the present day.

Comment: @Hamlet - That page shows up as a [paywall page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Nog.png) for me. Are you already a subscriber?

Comment: FYI, it shows as a paywall for me also. Not to dispute what Hamlet and Ily claim about it's contents, but a walled site only provides a reference point if you are a subscriber. The EO site however, is not paywalled.

Comment: @Toby - I suspect he's been a subscriber for so long, he's forgotten that  we mere mortals can't go straight in :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already fully clear from existing SE posts and common research materials (Not just ones behind paywalls)

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Well, if PeterShor writes up his comment that would be entirely new information that I've not seen any where else. Also, since when do we close questions that are substantially different simply because a similar question exists on a competent different site?

Comment: Richard - my reason comes down to offtopic: commonly available references. Not duplicate.

Comment: @RoryAlsop -  none of these answer my question of whether this was a normal usage in the 1700s in English

Comment: @RoryAlsop why can't we have an answer to this question in the EL&U database? Is there an older question somewhere in the archives that says *wife* also referred to an *unmarried* woman? BTW, slightly off topic, but would virgins, and maids have been called *wives*? I do not have a subscription to the OED so I would be very happy to see its entry transcribed within an answer.

Comment: See Kris' comment above. This isn't just OED. Look at the (free) etymonline link. Common reference material. That's just my vote anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what some eighteenth-century dictionaries have to say about *wife*. From John Kersey & Edward Phillips, [*The New World of Words: or, Universal English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PHBUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT709&dq=%22Wife+a+married+Woman,+whose+Will%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8s9iPxrPTAhXoz1QKHcJMBKMQ6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=%22Wife%20a%20married%20Woman%2C%20whose%20Will%22&f=false), sixth edition (1706):

> **Wife,** a married Woman, whose Will, in the judgment of the Law, is subject to that of her Husband; so that 'tis commonly said *She has no Will*, but *fulget radiis Mariti*, i. e. Shines with her Husband's Lustre.

The same definition of *A WIFE* (but with an etymological derivation from the Saxon *Wiff*) appears in various editions of Nathan Bailey, [*An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=b2vX0vFqXQcC&pg=PT614&dq=%22marry+a+wife%5D+a+married+woman%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHzqL2ybPTAhVGrFQKHVuUBIgQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22marry%20a%20wife%5D%20a%20married%20woman%22&f=false) (1724 and later).

From John Kersey, [*Dictionarium Anglo-Britannicum: or, a General English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=t01gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT504&dq=%22full+Moon+which+comes+before+any+great+moveable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI_YvMm8_YxgIVBouSCh1Ungh4#v=onepage&q=%22a%20married%20woman%22&f=false) (1708):

> **Wife**, a married Woman.

From Thomas Dyche & William Pardon, [*A New General English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l0JgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT844&dq=%22WIFE+(S.)+a+woman+that+is+married%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvm_rvx7PTAhVoqVQKHTavDfs4ChDoAQgnMAE#v=onepage&q=%22WIFE%20(S.)%20a%20woman%20that%20is%20married%22&f=false), first (?) edition (1735):

> **WIFE** (S.) A woman that is married.

From Samuel Johnson, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kyRWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT596&dq=bow+and+scrape&hl=en&sa=X&ei=T0X-VMyMPJLuoAT1vYBA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBzge#v=onepage&q=%22a%20woman%20that%20has%20a%20husband%22&f=false) (1756):

> **WIFE.** *s.* plural *wives*. ... **1.** A woman that has a husband. [Quotations from Shakespeare, Genesis, Milton, Dryden, and Pope omitted]. **2.** It is used for a woman of low employment. [Quotation from Bacon involving the deceptive vending practices of "strawberry wives" omitted].

As Johnson's entry indicates, there was a strand of usage in England, at least from the time of Francis Bacon (who died in 1626), of using the term *wife* to refer to a woman of mean occupation. It is certainly possible that native English speakers of the eighteenth century might on occasion refer to a [*fishwife*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishwife), who might or might not be married—and who certainly wasn't married to a fish—as simply a *wife*. (An [*alewife*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alewife), on the other hand *is* a fish.) Nevertheless, to judge from the dictionary entries above, the word *wife* was generally understood in the 1700s to refer to a married woman.

On the other hand, nothing in any of the cited definitions suggests that the man in the nursery rhyme who was "with seven wives" had to have been married to them himself in order for them to qualify as wives he was with.